# Ubuntu randomly freezes after bootup after switching to nvidia proprietary drivers

Tags: nvidia

After a minimal install of Ubuntu 18.04, I switched to using NVIDIA's proprietary drivers.

Recently, I've noticed that the screen would randomly freeze after boot up. Nothing works, I can't even enter text mode, till I hard reset.

Right now it is working fine but I'm typing this after restart. This typically occurs when I'm on Firefox. I can't figure out what might be causing this.

Comment: If you return to Nouveau, https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/ for a while, does the randome freezing persist?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling 3D acceleration on Firefox:
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/forum-response-disable-hardware-acceleration

If the problem occurs mainly on Firefox, it's maybe related to 3D acceleration with the nvidia driver.

I had a similar problem, but not only on firefox.
I have updated the system to Ubuntu 19.10 with the latest Nvidia driver and everything works fine.

It could be related to Linux kernel incompatibility with your motherboard, and there is a chance that this can be resolved on a more recent Linux kernel with a more recent Ubuntu, as in my case. I had a laptop with two graphics cards.

Comment: I'm trying to update to 19.10 and if the problem persists, I'll try disabling 3D acceleration. Thanks for your input.